# Failed to provisioning worker for TestDataflowRunner in asia-southeast1 zone

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

I have a question I'd like to ask about `TestDataflowRunner`.

I created a beam pipeline (Java) that runs using `DataflowRunner`. I deployed the worker in zone `asia-southeast1` belong with the network. The pipeline runs normally as expected in `DataflowRunner`. Therefore, I also want to create `@ValidatesRunner` tests using `TestDataflowRunner`. I've run the test using the same service account and the same network. The execution graph also looks loaded fine, but failed to provisioning the worker.

Following is the command that I use to run the tests.

```
task validatesRunnerTests(type: Test) {
  group = "Verification"
  description = "Run tests that require a Dataflow runner to validate that pipelines/transforms work correctly"

  systemProperty "beamTestPipelineOptions", JsonOutput.toJson([
    "--runner=TestDataflowRunner",
    "--project=$projectId",
    "--region=us-central1",
    "--workerZone=$zone",
    "--usePublicIps=false",
    "--network=$network",
    "--subnetwork=$subnetwork",
    "--tempRoot=$stagingBucket",
    "--serviceAccount=$serviceAccount",
  ])

  useJUnit {
    includeCategories 'org.apache.beam.sdk.testing.ValidatesRunner'
  }
}
```

The service account has included following roles.

1. `roles/dataflow.admin`
2. `roles/dataflow.worker`

I've only got following errors log, but I can't found any error logs in Stackdriver VM Instance.

```
2020-08-12 17:16:27.061 ICT Startup of the worker pool in zone asia-southeast1-a failed to bring up any of the desired 1 workers. The project quota may have been exceeded or access control policies may be preventing the operation; review the Stackdriver Logging "GCE VM Instance" log for diagnostics.
2020-08-12 17:16:27.095 ICT Workflow failed. Causes: Internal Issue (8c283568ab7f3c3c): 82159483:17
```

Does anyone know the problem and can help me?

Thank you

Comment: Have you reviewed Dataflow common issue [guidance](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/common-errors?hl=en#worker-pool-failure)  for this specific error case? It might help you to determine the root cause.

Comment: that sounds annoying. Sorry about the trouble @David Christianto. Do you have access to Dataflow support? Can you file a support ticket? (if not, we can figure it out some other way)

Comment: No, I don't @Pablo

Comment: can you please create an issue here, and share job IDs? https://b.corp.google.com/issues/new?component=187168&template=1162867

Comment: Hi @Pablo,
I'm sorry, I want to ask again, what username should I use to login?

Comment: I believe you were able to file a support ticket right? If so, that's great!

Comment: did Omar's answer help?

Answer (score 1):

The issue seems to be getting the job to launch with private IPs only. I launched a Dataflow job using the TestDataflowRunner, disabling public IPs.

I first cloned the WordCount repo [1], and made three changes to `WordCount.java`.

Added the following libs:

```
import org.apache.beam.sdk.testing.TestPipeline;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.testing.TestPipelineOptions;
```

Changed:

```
  public interface WordCountOptions extends PipelineOptions {
```

to

```
  public interface WordCountOptions extends TestPipelineOptions {
```

and

```
    Pipeline p = Pipeline.create(options);
```

to

```
    Pipeline p = TestPipeline.create(options);
```

I used Maven, and ran the following command:

```
mvn clean compile exec:java \
      -Dexec.mainClass=org.apache.beam.examples.WordCount \
      -Dexec.args=" \
      --project=$PROJECT_ID\
      --tempRoot=gs://mcbuckety/tempf 
      --output=gs://$BUCKET_NAME/testrundf \
      --runner=TestDataflowRunner 
      --usePublicIps=false 
      --subnetwork=regions/us-central1/subnetworks/private" 
      -Pdataflow-runner
```

The code compiled and launched a Dataflow job. I went to the GCE page to check that the VM did not have Public IPs, and that was indeed the case. I know the code is not strictly testing; I am not asserting anything, but I got the pipeline to launch.

[1] https://beam.apache.org/get-started/quickstart-java/#get-the-wordcount-code